# Inserir Vários registro na tabela PHP MYSQL

Tags: php

Estou tentando fazer um `INSERT` usando PHP para inserir vários registros no BD de uma só vez.

Meu código só está inserindo a primeira linha dos dados. Ele inclusive apresenta todos as linhas, mas, para inserir, somente a primeira é enviada ao BD.

```
include "conexao.php";

$arquivo = "txt/Coleta.TXT";
$objeto =  fopen($arquivo, 'r');

while($dados = fgets($objeto))
{
    $empresa = trim(substr($dados, 0, 4));
    $funcionario = trim(substr($dados, 4, 6));
    $local = trim(substr($dados, 10, 4));
    $cracha = trim(substr($dados, 14, 8));
    $data = trim(substr($dados, 22, 6));

    $data_dia = substr($data, 0, 2);    
    $data_mes = substr($data, 2, 2);
    $data_ano = substr($data, 4, 2);    
    $datames = "20$data_ano"."$data_mes"."$data_dia"; 
    $hora = trim(substr($dados, 28, 4));


    $sql_gravar = ("INSERT INTO cadhorames(codempre, codfunci, localfun, crachfun, datamfun, horafun) VALUE 
                  ('$empresa','$funcionario','$local','$cracha','$datames','$hora')");

    mysql_query($sql_gravar);


    ?>

<form name="arqtxt" >
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><? echo $empresa ?> </td>
            <td><? echo $funcionario ?> </td>
            <td><? echo $local ?> </td>
            <td><? echo $cracha ?> </td>
            <td><? echo $datames ?> </td>
            <td><? echo $hora ?> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?
}
fclose($objeto);


</form>
```

Exemplo do arquivo:

```
00030000020001000000021808140730
00030000020001000000021808141100
00030000020001000000021808141300
00030000020001000000021808141750
00030000030001000001231708140900
00030000030001000001231708141200
00030000030001000001231708141300
00030000030001000001231708141800
```

Comment: Verifique se não está tentando inserir dados duplicados em alguma coluna com chave única.

Comment: Value também existe! Values geralmente se usa quando tem intenção de adicionar mais de 1 registro na mesma query tipo: "values (...), (...), (...)". Jerry ele apresenta algum erro?

Comment: Eu sei que não tem muito a ver, mas não entendi pq o <form> esta no loop e fechando somente fora do loop?!

Comment: Mude `mysql_query($sql_gravar);` para `mysql_query($sql_gravar) or die(mysql_error());` veja se é exibido algum erro.

Comment: Siga a dica do @Premiere, dentro do loop monte a QUERY com os valores e execute 1 vez em seguida

Comment: Olá! pessoal.  eu coloquei para dar o erro.. e realmente ele gerou Duplicação de Chave.  ou seja,   todos vc´s estavam certos.   vou colocar para atualizar e conferir se tem registros.  Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Fiz alguns testes cujo neste link http://axitech.com.br/teste.php consegui fazer com que todos os registros fossem retornados dentro do while motivo pelo qual penso que agora você conseguirá fazer o `INSERT` sem problemas a partir da instrução do `while`.

Vou colocar o código aqui cujo o arquivo que guarda os dados é este: http://axitech.com.br/coleta.txt ... Basicamente os erros estavam nas instruções `PHP`, na verdade estava dando erro de PHP que eu detectei ao colar o código no Dreamweaver.

Eis o seu código minimamente modificado (comentei algumas partes por exemplo relacionados a conexão com o banco de dados). Ahhhh, coloquei a `table` antes do `form` e os dois fora do `while`:

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);
ini_set("display_errors", 0);
include ("conexao.php");
$arquivo = "coleta.txt";
$objeto =  fopen($arquivo, 'r');

echo '<form action="" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">';
echo '<table>';

while($dados = fgets($objeto))
{
    $empresa        = trim(substr($dados, 0, 4));
    $funcionario    = trim(substr($dados, 4, 6));
    $local          = trim(substr($dados, 10, 4));
    $cracha         = trim(substr($dados, 14, 8));
    $data           = trim(substr($dados, 22, 6));

    $data_dia       = substr($data, 0, 2);    
    $data_mes       = substr($data, 2, 2);
    $data_ano       = substr($data, 4, 2);    
    $datames        = "20$data_ano"."$data_mes"."$data_dia"; 
    $hora           = trim(substr($dados, 28, 4));


    /*
    $sql_gravar = ("INSERT INTO cadhorames(codempre, codfunci, localfun, crachfun, datamfun, horafun) VALUE 
                  ('$empresa','$funcionario','$local','$cracha','$datames','$hora')");

    mysql_query($sql_gravar);
    */


?>

<tr>
    <td><?php echo $empresa ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $funcionario ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $local ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $cracha ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $datames ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $hora ?> </td>
</tr>

<?php } 

echo '</table>';
echo '</form>';

fclose($objeto); 

?>
```

Lembrando, você deve **descomentar** a parte de inserção no banco de dados e também **reativar** os erros e warnings para mostrar novamente caso seu php tenha erros, comentei só para não aparecer erros relacionados ao `mysql`.

Comment: você pode usar o `http://www.phpfiddle.org` ou outro similar

Comment: Olá! Marcos
Eu fiz um teste com o seu Código.  ele não deu erro.
Porém,  eu tinha um problema q precisava resolver conforme a conversa que tive acima com os outros parceiros..  Tive problema com a Chave Primaria.  vou tentar resolver isso.
De qualquer forma agradeço muito sua atenção.  me ajudou na questão do Form tb.  Abraço

Answer (score 1):

Recomendo usar função `explode`:

```
$linhas = explode('\n',$arquivoTXT);
```

Aí você dá um:

```
foreach($linhas as $value) {
 // aqui você processa os dados de cada linha
 // e insere no banco de dados.
}
```